# Customize UINavigationItem Font

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

[image: Different fonts]

I am trying to customize the font for my UINavigationController, and I can add `largeTitleText` and modify the title text however I want, but I seem unable to change the font of the UINavigationItem text.

I've searched around google, the apple developer docs, and don't seem to find a method to call to modify the appearance of the item font.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(_:for:) - not working for you?

Comment: @DanielH yeah that worked. thanks if you want to make it the answer

Comment: glad it works. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(_:for:)
```

Not working for you?